# Ruby Regex for price

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This one fails when a zero is at the end

12.12 passes
5.51 passes
12.50 fails
12.60 fails

```
 price_regex = /^\d+(\.\d{2})?$/
```

why? and how do I fix it?

Some more info

in _form.html.erb

```
  <p>
    <%= f.label :price %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </p>
```

in menu_item.rb

```
  price_regex = /^\d+(\.\d{2})?$/
  validates :price, :presence => true,
                :format => {  :with => price_regex  }
```

in menu_items_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @menu_item = MenuItem.new(params[:menu_item])

    if @menu_item.save
     respond_with @menu_item, :location => menu_items_url
   else
     flash[:notice] = "Not Saved"
       end
   end
```

price is a decimal in the database with a precision of 2.

Comment: `'12.50'` matches that regex just fine, are you sure you don't have `n = 12.50; s = n.to_s` going on somewhere?

Comment: I appended my question with more info.  it works on rubular but for some reason it trips invalid when i submit the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Rails 3 with the client_side_validations gem, which means I need a Regexp that works both in Ruby and Javascript.  I also have a clear delineation between frontend and backend format--The user should never be able to enter "$12.5", but once it hits the server, I don't care about the trailing 0.

My solution was to add a core extension (in my case, for Float, but BigDecimal would probably be more appropriate in most cases):

```
class Float
  def can_convert_to_i_with_no_loss_of_precision
    (self % 1).zero?
  end
  alias_method :to_s_with_loss_of_trailing_zeroes, :to_s
  def to_s
    if can_convert_to_i_with_no_loss_of_precision
      to_i.to_s
    else
      "#{to_s_with_loss_of_trailing_zeroes}#{0 if (self * 10 % 1).zero?}"
    end
  end
end
```

Now I can use this in a Model, and it plays nicely on the front end (Javascript doesn't convert it to a Float, so the user will always be forced to enter 2 digits after the decimal) and on the backend (where ActiveModel's FormatValidator will call `to_s` and the core extension will know when to add the trailing 0):

```
validates :price, :format => { :with => /^\d+(\.\d{2})?$/, :allow_blank => true }
```

Answer (score 3):

You say that `price` is "a decimal in the database with a precision of 2". That means that `price` is being represented as a BigDecimal in Ruby and the regex test will be done on the string form of that BigDecimal. A little bit of experimentation will clarify things:

```
> p = BigDecimal.new('12.50')
 => #<BigDecimal:12a579e98,'0.125E2',18(18)> 
> p.to_s
 => "12.5"
```

And so your regex will fail. You shouldn't be using a regex for this at all, regexes are meant for strings but you're checking a number. You should be able to keep using your regex if you allow for the conversion:

```
/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

Comment: If I don't want to use a regex, what's the best way to validate user input limiting them to two places after the decimal?

Comment: @ctilley79: If `p` was the price, you could check `(p*100).floor == p*100`, that would still let `11.500` through as `11.5` but I wouldn't worry about that any more than I'd worry about `11` not having exactly two digits after the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

The regex looks fine to me. I tested it at [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) with the inputs you mentioned and a few more, and it captures all of them correctly.

The problem is likely with some other part of the code. Maybe you are using `price = <regex>`, whereas you should be using `price =~ <regex>` to match a string with a regex.

Comment: I get a pretty nasty undefined local variable when i use price_regex =~ /^\d+(\.\d{2})?$/